# Session problems when using Integrated Application Pool with ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

I'm developing an ASP.net MVC application with Entity Framework. I'm trying to use custom authorization in my code, it works fine in my PC but when I deploy it, it doesn't work.

Basically in my custom AuthorizeAttribute, I use this code as constructor:

```
public Auth(User.eUserType requiredRole)
{
    _user = StaticManager.getCurrentUser();
    _requiredRole = requiredRole;
}
```

It gets the current active user from the session like this:

```
return HttpContext.Current.Session["User"];
```

It's pretty simple stuff and it works in my local PC. I doesn't work when I deploy it, session objects seems `null`. Here is the thing, when I change my application pool setting to Classic in the server, it works.

My first question is why? Why session doesn't work in Integrated mode? Second one is, what happens if I use the Classic setting. I'm developing with MVC so is there any difference? Should i use it?

Thanks

Comment: add database server name & password in your web.config file